How Activity diagram should be?
i am making an activity diagram about an online train reservation system i want just to ask if what i did is correct or could it be better and how in general should activity diagram be ?


Notation looks correct, but I never saw an activity diagram "in the wild".

Feedback for the process you described:
From the meaning I wonder what does "book ticket" actually mean? Isn't that more the name for the whole process the diagram describes?
What availability is checked, if source and destination and all the other information is entered after that step?
Do really all steps between "Fill form" and "Make payment" happen in parallel?
Although the payment process involves several nodes, it still looks a bit too simple to me, especially because you involve a credit card - this for sure would involve at lease one other system like the payment providers - maybe you better skip that option and only offer "pay by balance" - but even then, you should include a deduction of the balance by the tickets price. And where is the price calculated?
Maybe the passenger also wants to confirm the booking after he was shown the price but before the money is actually taken?
Also the exception handler for "Not enough money" should probably not involve such a complex thing like "Add funds" - because this again involves a complete payment process. Maybe it is better to just "display error" there, or "cancel booking".
By "confirmation" do you mean to send an email to the customer? The description is a bit unclear for me, maybe you can describe it a bit more detailed.
And finally: the booking system for sure would store a bought ticket internally so later its validity can be checked. This should maybe happen before the confirmation to the passenger.
